# How to deal with heteroscedasticty: choosing between White, WLS or Log linear model?

Tags: regression, heteroscedasticity

I am dealing with heteroscedasticity, and as we learned several methods to deal with the issue, I would like your help in choosing which one.

The problem comes out of the econometrics book of Verbeek. I am trying to predict the price of a house with the lot size of the house. This is a plot of the data with a linear model fit, and the absolute value of the residuals plotted against the predictor:

[image]

I know the following options to correct for heteroscedasticty:

- Stick with OLS, but correct the standard errors with White
- Use weighted linear regression, but as you can see on the plots below, the estimate changes and although the standard error of the estimate is smaller, the goodness of fit decreases slightly.
- Log transform your outcome variable, so you deal with relative increases. A disadvantage though is that the fit is no longer linear, and the value of an extra square meter is higher for greater lot sizes. This seems a bit counterintuitive to me, I would rather say that the difference in price for a 500 meter square or 501 meter square is smaller than between a 50 and 51 meter square lot.

[image]

Which method do you recommend for this case?

Comment: Your intuition might be aided by the thought that as lot size goes up, many other price-determining factors typically change, too: on average, larger lots are sites for bigger and *fancier* houses with more amenities, higher quality materials, and so on.

Answer (score -2):

The problem of heteroskedasticity is that the variance of the residuals of the model are not constant but rather a function of time - VARx(t). Typically as time increases so does the variance as we can see in your photo. The most simple check whether heteroskedasticity is corrected is to see if the residuals of your model are normal. My advice is to always use logs ( in your case - log( price ) and log ( lotsize )  in such cases because they ussually do the job and the estimators are BLUE and C ( best linear unbiases and consistent ). When using WLS you can get biased estimators.

Hope it helped !

Comment: (1) Where does time appear in the question? (2) Taking logs looks like a reasonable option here.  But please note that an estimator that is BLUE for the original data is almost certainly not going to be BLUE for the logarithms. Moreover, a model that is linear in the original data will not be linear in the logarithms.